# Maven Access denied AuthorizationException local LAN Nexus

Tags: maven

I am getting the following error with Nexus on LAN:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could  not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-  plugin:pom:1.3.5.RELEASE from/to nexus (http://ma
venrepo.dev.au.service.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Access denied to:    http://mavenrepo.dev.au.service.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-pl
ugin/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.5.RELEASE.pom, ReasonPhrase: Forbidden.
....
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to:           http://mavenrepo.dev.au.service.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springfra     mework/boot/spring-b
oot-maven-plugin/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.5.RELEASE.pom,   ReasonPhrase: Forbidden.
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.resourceExists(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:707)
```

The pom is accessible from browser without authentication needed.
Username and password exist in the settings file and works fine for some devs but not for some other. We have tried with or without credentials with no luck.

environment: Maven 3.3.9, Java 1.8, Windows 7 , NO proxy.

To me seems more like a Windows firewall/network problem as this same project runs on a guest linux on virtualbox.

Maven trace logs also didn't add anything.

Any idea?

Comment: execute on command line this Maven command: `mvn help:effective-settings` and compare the results

Comment: It looks like you nexus needed some kind of authentication which the message ` Access denied to:    http://mavenrepo.dev.au.service.com/nexus/content/groups/publi` let think...

Answer (score 0):

We replaced nexus name with ip and this started working so it wasn't authentication. Strange thing is that same name url resolves correctly in browser and wget.

I assume this has to do with the way maven resolves name to ip...